# jquery delay and setTimeout

Tags: jquery, delay, settimeout, fadein, fadeout

I'm trying to stall the hiding of a span while the other spans fadein over top of it, but delay and settimeout don't seem to be working, on mouseout the page flashes white before the other 3 images fade in on top.  The delay is on the mouseout function.  Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cujgR/5/)

```
  $("#top-left").mouseover(function() {
        $("#bottom-left").fadeOut(200);
        $("#bottom-right").fadeOut(200);
        $("#top-right").fadeOut(200);
        $( this ).css( "width","+=400");
        $( this ).css( "height","+=250" );
        $( this ).css( "z-index", "-1");
    });
  $("#top-left").mouseout(function() {
        $("#bottom-left").fadeIn(200);   
        $("#bottom-right").fadeIn(200);
        $("#top-right").fadeIn(200).delay(10000);
        setTimeout(function() {
                $( this ).css( "width","-=400");
                $( this ).css( "height","-=250" );
                $( this ).css( "z-index", "1");
        },400);
    });
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fire the last part as a callback on the animations:

```
$("#top-right").fadeIn(200, function() {
  $("#top-left").css( "width","-=400").css( "height","-=250" ).css( "z-index", "1");
});
```

that way it won't execute until the animation is done.

Comment: +1 Beat me! Callback functions are JS' way of chaining events. `settimeout()` isn't always reliable, either.

Comment: Totally didn't think of a Callback, I'll try it out.